# issue with accessing a variable in a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

This list of tuples is passed to the class on instantiation, which is when the class is created or the initializer is called.  Getting TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'error.  Help!  I'm relatively new to this and can't figure it out!

```
class MedReport:
    def __init__(self,patients):
        self.patientname = patients[0]
        self.serum = patients[1]
       

    def reports(self):
        patientList = self.__dict__.values()
        index = 0
        
        for patients in patientList:
            if self.serum >= 80:
                print(self.patientname[index] + " has a heightened serum level")
            elif ((self.serum[index] > 40) and (self.serum[index] < 79)):
                print(self.patientname[index] + " has a moderate risk for infections")
            else:
                print(self.patientname[index] + " does not have a risk factor")
        index += 1

patients = [("John Blake", 22),("Jane Smith", 35),("Henry Baker", 77),("Thomas Cooper", 87)]

data = MedReport(patients)
data.reports()
```

Comment: `patients[0]` is `("John Blake", 22)` and `patients[1]` is `("Jane Smith", 35)`.

Comment: `self.serum[index]` is returning a tuple you need to access the value inside that tuple that you want to compare against `40` and `79`. Judging by the comment above it would be `self.serum[index][1]`

Comment: you are trying to instantiate a lot of patients at once, but you dont handle it in you code, what happend in your __init__ is that self.patientname keep the first element of you parient list which is the whole type ("John Blake", 22), and self.serum = patients[1] takes the second element of your patient list ("Jane Smith", 35) and the rest if patient is ignored

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you expected `patients[0]` to return a list of all the `[0]` elements (the names) of the list of tuples, and `patients[1]` to return all the `[1]` elements. Indexing is not automatically distributed over list elements like that -- it's just indexing the list itself. As a result, you're setting `self.patientname` to the tuple `("John Blake", 22)`, and `self.serum` to the tuple `("Jane Smith", 35)`.

What you should do is save the entire `patients` list in an attribute, then extract the components when you loop over it.

```
class MedReport:
    def __init__(self,patients):
        self.patientlist = patients

    def reports(self):
        for index, (patientname, serum) in enumerate(self.patientlist):
            if serum >= 80:
                print(patientname + " has a heightened serum level")
            elif 40 < serum < 79
                print(patientname + " has a moderate risk for infections")
            else:
                print(patientname + " does not have a risk factor")

patients = [("John Blake", 22),("Jane Smith", 35),("Henry Baker", 77),("Thomas Cooper", 87)]

data = MedReport(patients)
data.reports()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a tuple to an integer. When you execute this `self.serum = patients[1]`, you aren't getting an integer value, but instead a tuple.

Example: `self.serum = patients[1]` is retrieving this: `("Jane Smith", 35)`
To retrieve the integer inside the tuple you have to do this: `self.serum = patients[#index][0]`